# Returning ViewComponent views as HtmlStrings for manipulation within other ViewComponents

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

We are building a custom reporting engine built on top of razor for our own internal use, and so far everything is going pretty well. However, we've begun breaking the initial prototype code into functions inside of the ReportViewer view to make maintenance a bit easier, but we're running into some issues.

The original prototype code (in a very simplified form), looks something like this:

```
@foreach (var widget in Model.ReportWidgets)
{
    var longSide = Model?.DisplayOptions?.DisplayMedium?.Long ?? 0;
    var units = Model?.DisplayOptions?.DisplayMedium?.Units ?? "px";
    var height = widget.Rows * (longSide / Model.RowsPerPage);
    var width = widget.Columns / Model.Columns * 100;
    <div style="float: left;height: @(height)@(units); width: @(width)%">
        @(await InvokeComponent(widget))
    </div>    
}
```

And we're effectively trying to break this into functions that would look more like:

```
public async Task<HtmlString> BuildContainer(IReportWidget widget)
{
    var longSide = Model?.DisplayOptions?.DisplayMedium?.Long ?? 0;
    var units = Model?.DisplayOptions?.DisplayMedium?.Units ?? "px";
    var height = widget.Rows * (longSide / Model.RowsPerPage);
    var width = widget.Columns / Model.Columns * 100;
    var openDeclaration = $"<div style='float:left;height: {height}{units};width: {width}>";
    var component = await InvokeComponent(widget);
    var closeDeclaration = "</div>";

    return new HtmlString(openDeclaration + component + closeDeclaration); 
}

public async Task<IHtmlContent> InvokeComponent(IReportWidget widget)
{
    return await Component.InvokeAsync("AnalyticsWidget", new {widget = widget});
}
```

However, since the ViewComponent returns a `IViewComponentResult`, this doesn't render cleanly in our HtmlString. Instead it just spits out `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.ViewBuffer` in place of the ViewComponent.

How would we go about getting this to work with razor?

For reference, we're porting the system from our client-side Javascript-based version. In essence, they're identical, but this version will load all components server-side rather than client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that if you are able to transform the result from `InvokeComponent` into `String` this problem should be solved. So, why don't you try this to get the string from the IHtmlContent:

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
System.IO.StringWriter writer = new System.IO.StringWriter(sb);
System.Text.Encoding asciiEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
System.Text.Encodings.Web.HtmlEncoder hEncoder= System.Text.Encodings.Web.HtmlEncoder.Default;
component.WriteTo(writer, hEncoder);
String htmlString = writer.toString();
```